# Cannot click on a button which have a specific attribute

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using [puppeteer-sharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/) for get content loaded by AJAX from a web page. I need to submit a form which have the following structure:

```
<form action="" method="post" _lpchecked="1">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title"><label for="login-username1">Username</label></div>
        <div>
            <input class="int-text" type="text" id="login-username1" name="login-username" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off" >
            <span class="required" title="required item">*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title"><label for="login-password1">Password</label></div>
        <div>
            <input class="int-text" type="password" id="login-password1" name="login-password" size="25" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="required" title="required item">*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <button type="submit" name="login-submit" class="inline-btn-2"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

First, I filled the two inputs available: `login-username1` and `login-password1`, using the following code:

```
using (Page page = await Browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.GoToAsync("https://www.oddsportal.com/login/");
    await page.TypeAsync("#login-username1", "sfarzoso");
    await page.TypeAsync("#login-password1", "password");

    await page.ClickAsync("name=login-submit");
    await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
    var c = await page.GetContentAsync();
}
```

the problem is that the button doesn't have an `id` but just a `name` attribute, so my code return:

> PuppeteerSharp.EvaluationFailedException: 'Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'name=login-submit' is not a valid selector.
>       at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:1:33'

this error happen on

```
await page.ClickAsync("name=login-submit");
```

the method `ClickAsync` want a selector, and the button just have a unique `name`, seems that I'm not able to click on that button though.

NB: `Browser` variable is instantiated as following:

```
Browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CHROME_PATH"),
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `CSS selector` as a locator then you haven't provided correct locator.

You can try following CSS Selector which should work.

Using `Type` attribute

```
await page.ClickAsync("button[type='submit']");
```

OR Using `name` attribute

```
 await page.ClickAsync("button[name='login-submit']");
```

OR using `class` attribute

```
await page.ClickAsync("button.inline-btn-2");
```

OR Using `multiple attribute` such as

```
await page.ClickAsync("button[type='submit'][name='login-submit']");
```

Comment: I changed the accepted answer because you has suggested: `button[type='submit']` which has solved the multiple button with same class issue. Thanks to both anyway

Answer (score 2):

`"name=login-submit"` is not a valid [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). This should work for you:

```cs
await page.ClickAsync("button[name='login-submit']");
```

Comment: just a question: why the user is not logged in on `var c = await page.GetContentAsync();`?

Comment: If you open the browser with headless in false you do see the page being refreshed?